# "Async" "Differ" tags in stiefinity breaks the layout in sitefinity

Tags: pagespeed, sitefinity

We are trying to optimize pagespeed as recommended by SEO team, but when we add differ or async tag it breaks my entire design.

Need help with an alternative solution so that my page doesn't break even after using the tags

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "defer", but what doesn't work specifically? Is there a public page to look at?

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Ye I mean defer tag. I cannot share the page extremely sorry for that

Comment: Can you share where/how your adding them?

Comment: <script async src="myscript.js"></script>

<script defer src="myscript.js"></script>

Comment: Sorry no, I mean in Sitefinity... are you using Content Blocks, are they literally just added to your .cshtml as script tags?